# NSInternalInconsistencyException in folly::detail::function::FunctionTraits<bool (folly::dynamic const&, folly::dynamic const&) const>

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase, bugsnag

Bugsnag full error:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException in
> folly::detail::function::FunctionTraits<bool (folly::dynamic const&,
> folly::dynamic const&)
> const>::uninitCall(folly::detail::function::Data&, folly::dynamic
> const&, folly::dynamic const&)  Call must be made on main thread.

I m getting this error in the bugnag and in the production build. This error is random. Not able to reproduce. And only comes in the ios build. iOS OS version: `14.0` or `14.0.1`.

[image]

As per the bugsnag log, I m able to find that error is related to the firebase push notification. Firebase push notification integrated into my application.

Below are the versions used in the app :

- react-native-firebase: 5.5.5
- react: 16.9.0
- react-native: 0.61.4.